# MySql update statement in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I'm struggling with an update statement using php. The problem occurs when the string in the variable `$fltr` contains more than one word.

`$fltr ="Two Words or More"` does not work

`$fltr="OneWordOnly"` works fine.

require_once('includes/init.php');

```
$Login = new Login( $db );

if(empty($_SESSION['logged']))
{
    $Login->_logout();
}
if(isset($_SESSION['uid']))
{
    $userid=(int)$_SESSION['uid'];
}
$fltr = $_GET['filter'];
$fltr= pg_escape_string($fltr);
$deakt="D";

$updSQL="update class_products set FTP ='".$deakt."' where title ='".$fltr."' and owner =".$userid;
$db->query($updSQL) or die ("Error in query: $updSQL " . mysql_error());

$txt='<textarea style="margin-left:250px;margin-top:110px; font-family:verdana:font-size:14px;color:#000;">Search filter {$fltr} is deactivated</textarea>';
$class_tpl->assign('txt', $txt);

//now display the template
$class_tpl->display('cbUpdate.tpl.php');
```

Normally I would print the $updSQL to see the what the problem is, but I am using this in a LightBox variant and having problems debugging.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: What error do you get? Are you sure there is a record with a `title` of "Two Words or More"?

Comment: I really hope for your sake all those values are [properly escaped](http://bobby-tables.com/php) because most of the time string concatenation is a sure sign it's [not](http://bobby-tables.com/).

Comment: Not getting an error message, that is one of the problems

Comment: `where title ='".$fltr."'` column names must not contain spaces unless wrapped in backticks. Sounds to me like your columns contain spaces. @user2120143 Most likely the reason, far as I can tell.

Comment: how would you wrap backticks into this?

Comment: Good question. Try: where title =`\``'".$fltr."'`\`` having a backtick before `'"` and after `"'`

Comment: ^--« Scratch that, it's not the case. I tested your present code having `space a` and `space b` as entries in my DB (with multiple same) and it worked fine. Something else is causing this. @user2120143 Any chance of seeing full code?

Comment: ok, thank you for trying. I am doing a lot of update statements in our system, but this value is fetched from an URL like this `code`$fltr = $_GET['filter']; @fred -ii

Comment: You're welcome. I suggest you place your code that you're using in your question instead, it will surely help someone else to pick up on it. In the meantime, can you try `WHERE title ='$fltr'`?

Comment: your code is **totally unsecure**, please use **parameterised query**, use `bindParam()`, `bindValue()` functions to bind your parameters. Don't every concatenate your parameters directly to `SQL`

Answer (score 0):

My *guess* is the value is urlencoded, and you need to [urldecode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.urldecode.php) it, before escaping.

Comment: Tried this, but made no change:

Comment: Then you need to get the error message from the logs and/or print out the actual value of `$fltr`.